# beautifulsoup4 getting second paragraph and form

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to print out the paragraph from second `<p>` and the form method inside a webpage. However, I can only find a way to print out the first paragraph. My HTML structure looks like this:

```
<body>
    <p> part1 </p>
    <p> part2 </p>
    <form method="post"> <p> content inside form </p> </form>
</body>
```

What should i do if i just want to print out the content from paragraph of part2 and the form individually?
So far i have:

```
b = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml");
#this print out p of part 1
print b.p.text
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the content in the second `p` you can use `findNext`

```
secondP = print b.find("p").findNext("p").get_text()
print secondP
```

To find the content in the form you can get the `form` tag and then pull the `p` tag out of that

```
formP = soup.find("form", attrs={ "method" : "post" }).find("p").get_text()
print formP
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to access the form and the second paragraph

Answer (score 1):

Use `find_all()` to get a list of all of the `p` tags.  Access the 2nd tag in the list (at index 1).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''<body>
    <p> part1 </p>
    <p> part2 </p>
    <form method="post"> <p> content inside form </p> </form>
</body>'''

b = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "lxml")
print b.find_all('p')[1].text
```

> **find_all()**
>
> Signature: find_all(name, attrs, recursive, string, limit,
>   **kwargs)
>
> The `find_all()` method looks through a tag’s descendants and retrieves
>   all descendants that match your filters.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

Comment: Thanks you very much! it's a very easy syntax to access the 2nd tag